# get value of property in object literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

this.units gives me an undefined. How do i acces this value? Or do you would set this whole thing up differently? maybe you guys could help me?

```
var calculator = calculator || {};

(function() {

calculator.sliderValues = {
    applications: 42,
    capacity: 140,
    activeData: 30,
    performance: 30,
    virtualized: 100
}

calculator.overview = {
    apps: {
        HighPerformanceApps: {
            units: Math.ceil(calculator.sliderValues.applications/100 * calculator.sliderValues.performance),
            virtualized: calculator.sliderValues.virtualized < 81 ? 0 : this.units
        }
    }
}

})();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To learn about context, it'd be helpful to console.log(this).

Answer (score -1):

## update 2:

## [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/ad46a03d15c31df2d11333116db35836)

**it's because `this` refers to window object`

Comment: methinks OP mean `console.log(calculator.overview.apps.HighPerformanceApps.virtualized);` is _undefined_

Comment: And I mean it's defined as 13. What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: you log `units` i mean `virtualized` that calculation depends on `units`, [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvgqdY)

Comment: ah i see, still doens't really solve my problem. How do i acces the units property? Or is this just not the prefered way to set this up? I'm making an calculator with lots of variables and objects.

Comment: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201312/Blog/JavaScript-Prototype-Vs-Revealing-Module-Pattern/

Comment: check that out. Should help you understand good js patterns for this kind of thing.